# Compute the intersection and difference of multiple polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I have multiple (possibly concave) simple polygons, and need to compute the union and difference of them, some polygons have to be added, some subtracted from the final shape. I have found algorithms that can compute the intersection andthe difference of 2 polygons, but because they can produce multiple polygons simply running these multiple times would end up being super inefficent, is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: If I am right, $A-B+C+D-E+F-G$ is equivalent to $(A+C+D+F)-(E+G)$. But when the polygons are disjoint, their union is still multiple polygons.